# How can I put multiple values for ng-disabled in angular js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I put multiple values for ng-disabled in angular js?

My problem is explained with this following JS fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/FJf4v/10/

```
    <div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="myCnt">

    <h3>A ->> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="check"> </input></h3>
    <h3>B ->> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="check"> </input></h3>  

    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="check">Chkbox1 to be disabled</input>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="check">Chkbox2 to be disabled</input>
    <hr/>
</div>
</div>

Javascript:
function myCnt($scope) {
//
}
```

In this fiddle, there are total 4 check boxes labeled as A, B, Chkbox1 and Chkbox2.
What I am looking for is to disable both chkbox1 and chkbox2 after checking one of A and B checkboxes. However, its done halfway. If you click on either A or B, both these buttons are getting checked and below chkboxes are getting disabled. But, I dont want to get checked both A and B checkboxes if I just click on any one of them.

I hope, you will get my question.

Thank you !!

Comment: like that http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/FJf4v/11/ ?

Comment: @DotDotDot: Thanks a lot !! Is there a global way or simpler way if I have to many ng-models?

Comment: If you have a really long list of models, you can do it using a function and an object for the models, but it's too long to explain in the comments, so I will post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, as I said in the comments, if you want to achieve this with a very long list of checkboxes, you can try this way : (yeah for this example "very long" means 10)

**The models**
You can use a simple object which will contain all the values of the checkboxes, I did this using a ng-repeat, but it could be anything, just use the same iterable object :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="nb in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]" ng-model="checkModels[nb]" /></h3>
```

This object is initialized in the controller, I didn't specify any value, but you could for example set some checkboxes here :

```
$scope.checkModels={};
```

**The disabling function**
Nothing very difficult here, instead of a long list of || values, we will iterate through the models and return true as soon as we find a checked box :

```
    $scope.isThisDisabled=function(){
     for(var i in $scope.checkModels)
     {
         if($scope.checkModels[i])
             return true             
     }
    return false;
}
```

Then, we can use this function in the HTML :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="isThisDisabled()">Chkbox1 to be disabled</input>
```

The modified fiddle to test this : http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/FJf4v/12/

Have fun

Comment: Re your disabling function, I'd like to point out that underscore.js fits this gap and many others very neatly.
http://underscorejs.org/
It reduces the need to write such loops.

Comment: @DrewR, sure there are many implementations in many libraries, but I'm not sure you will gain perfs using a library only for this, considering the loading time etc... But honestly I've never run tests on this, it would be a good idea on a big project using a large number of loops, but for this example, I'm not sure it's really needed ;)

Comment: I made the comment without regard to performance or loading times, but that said underscore is 5kb minified and is tried and tested. 
For me it's all about making life easier for oneself, which underscore definitely does for this kind of repetitive task. The whole loop and function call can be replaced by _.contains(checkModels,true) directly in the ng-disabled attribute.

Answer (score 16):

Use two seperate variables i.e checkA and checkB. Then for ng-disabled use the logical OR operator like this:

```
ng-disabled="checkA || checkB"
```

I think this is what you are trying to achieve...?

Comment: Thanks a lot !! This is what I was looking for... Is there a global way or simpler way if I have to many ng-models?

Comment: You could declare a function within your controller to do the OR'ing if you have a lot of checkboxes. This would at least remove some of the verbosity required in the ng-disabled.  
If you have a lot of checkboxes though, I'd recommend using ng-repeat as DotDotDot suggests.

Comment: Hey @Drew R, Please don't mind it. The answer I was looking for is answered by DotDotDot, thats why! Yours answer is also correct but according to me, the more proper way is other way, thats why !! Your ans is also recommended for others who are working on a small app !!