# How do I add multiple conditions to "ng-disabled"?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to check that two conditions are **both** true before enabling a button:

Here is an example:

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="frmUser.pw2.$error.pwMatch" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ChangePassword()">Change</button>
```

This example only contains one condition within `ng-disabled`.  How would I add another such as a scope variable?

Comment: Why the down-vote and movement to close?

Comment: @scrowler-- So, you are saying that AngularJS won't have a problem with me making the same declaration twice in the same element?  Maybe my understanding of HTML isn't the problem.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You should be able to `&&` the conditions:

```
ng-disabled="condition1 && condition2"
```

Comment: Thanks--I am new to Angular and was enclosing the expression in braces.

Comment: Or you can use ng-disabled="condition1 || condition2" , is depend of you logic conditional.

Answer (score 23):

Wanny is correct. The `&&` operator doesn't work in HTML. With Angular, you must use the double pipes (`||`)for multiple conditions.

Comment: well, this answer is not correct. && means logical AND, || means logical OR. So if both your conditions need te be true for the control to be disabled use &&. If one or both need to be true, use ||.

Comment: @Reto can you please take a look to my jsbin ?Using the operator && AND the button is enabled with only 1 condition. Using the || OR the button is enabled only when both conditions are true.

Comment: I looked at your jsbin. I think you are confusing yourself with all those "NOT" !. It works as expected. Try not to use double negation, then all those logical expressions suddenly make a lot more sense and you (and anybody else) can understand your code much easier: instead of !$vaild use $invalid, instead of !items.length write items.length > 0.

Comment: Maybe you are right, this is the new bin, http://output.jsbin.com/rovimesuso/1/ ( there are no !  this time ).

Comment: How come so many people have upvoted this incorrect answer? && works fine in Angular expressions.

Comment: @WannyMiarelli You seem to be mixing several incomplete ideas about what you want to demonstrate in your updated jsbin example. I am not able to make sense of it. What I can say is that && works perfectly well as a logical AND operator, and if you change the value of $scope.f to true, then you will see that it triggers ng-disabled, just like it should when it is provided with two true values.

Comment: @Sammi if you switch the $scope.t to true and $scope.f to false ( 1 true and 1 false ) you will be able to click the button ( using the && operator ). To disable the button until both are true you have to use the logical operator " || ". The OP wants to enable the button ONLY if BOTH are true.

Comment: @WannyMiarelli Yes the OP actually wants a ||, as other answers have pointed out, but this answer that we are discussing isn't about that. It is wrongly stating that && doesn't work, when in fact it does. && does exactly what it is supposed to do. && means logical AND, and will trigger ng-disabled when both variables are true. || means logical OR, and will trigger it when either is true.

Comment: @Sammi the answer is not written by me. I just pointed out ( as you can see ) that in this specific case && is not the right choice. That's all.

Answer (score 15):

There is maybe a bit of a gotcha in the phrasing of the original question:

> I need to check that two conditions are both true before enabling a button

The first thing to remember that the ng-disabled directive is evaluating a condition under which the button should be, well, *disabled*, but the original question is referring to the conditions under which it should en *enabled*.  It will be enabled under any circumstances where the ng-disabled expression is not "truthy".

So, the first consideration is how to rephrase the logic of the question to be closer to the logical requirements of ng-disabled.  The logical inverse of checking that two conditions are true in order to enable a button is that if *either* condition is **false** then the button should be disabled.

Thus, in the case of the original question, the pseudo-expression for ng-disabled is "disable the button if condition1 is false **or** condition2 is false".  Translating into the Javascript-like code snippet required by Angular (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), we get:

!condition1 || !condition2

Zoomlar has it right!

Comment: Well-stated analysis of the question--your answer will definitely be useful to others who land on this page.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you wrap the condition in the correct precedence

```
ng-disabled="((!product.img) || (!product.name))"
```

Answer (score 9):

Actually the ng-disabled directive works with the " || " logical operator for me. The " && " evaluate only one condition.

http://jsbin.com/kuqilejesi/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Can you please motivate the down vote. Just to let me know where is my mistake.

Comment: Even though I did not downvote you, I understand the reason: Your answer is plain wrong: "the ng-disabled directive" works with any expression and will disable the control when the expression evaluates to truthy. Whether || or && is a totally different question (logical OR vs AND)

Comment: Got it, thanks. Just wanted to share the fact that the && operator has a strange behavior with the ng-directive.

Comment: sorry, there is absolutly no "strange behaviour" - it is behaving exactly like the JS && operator: a logical AND operator, that only evaluates the second argument if it is needed to determine that final result. E.g.  "a && b" -> if a is false you don't need to evaluate b, the result is anyway "false"

Comment: Yes ( look at my answer : "  The " && " evaluate only one condition. " , and this is why the && operator is not the right solution if you need to check for multiple conditions in order to enable / disable the button.

Comment: This is another well made answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261685/how-can-i-put-multiple-values-for-ng-disabled-in-angular-js

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
<button class="button" ng-disabled="(!data.var1 && !data.var2) ? false : true">
</button>
```

Its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Both variable must be false for the button to be disabled:

```
<button class="button" ng-disabled="(!data.var1 && !data.var2) ? false : true">
</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

this way worked for me

ng-disabled="(user.Role.ID != 1) && (user.Role.ID != 2)"