# ng-disabled not evaluating to false

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a button disabled if form fields are not valid.

```
<button ng-click="createData()" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Continue</button>
```

And above is working fine. The issue is when I add other condition to evaluate along with it

```
<button ng-click="createData()" ng-disabled="((isThisDisabled()) && (form.$invalid))">Continue</button>
```

It should also work as same as I am returning false in the function.

```
 $scope.isThisDisabled=function(){
     return false; 
  }
```

As per the links I have read there on [How to add multiple conditions to ng-disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555858/how-do-i-add-multiple-conditions-to-ng-disabled) it should work.

Comment: `form.$invalid` would be `true` for the button to be disabled, you need to return `true` from your function

Comment: logically `true && true` gives `true` which makes the button disabled. Now when form will be valid it will be `true && false` which is still `true` so button will never be enabled

Comment: `true && false` is `false`